# Is there a possibility that 'clean' method doesn't see a makefile.gcc?

Tags: c++, makefile, wxwidgets, mingw32

I'm trying to build a wxWidgets 3.0.4 and I'm following these instructions:

```
gcc -v

mingw32-make -v
cd /D C:\wxWidgets-3.0.4\build\msw
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc clean
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1
```

But when I'm trying to use step number 4 with `clean` I've got an error : 
`make (e=2) the system cannot find the file specified`.
The makefile.gcc is in the directory in which I'm using this command but the command cannot see this file.
What can I do in this situation?
EDIT:
These are the prinoutf from cmd after step 4: 
https://pastebin.com/S4LaBXk6

Comment: Do the other commands execute?

Comment: Also try with the `-d` flag to output detailed debug infos.

Comment: I think that error is due to `make` failing to run a command in the makefile, not due to not finding the makefile itself.

Comment: So i tried  mingw32-make -d makefile.gcc clean and here is the result: No implicit rule found for 'clean'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'clean'.
Must remake target 'clean'.
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.

Comment: @Macmade The first 3 steps executed properly

Comment: @donq104 I was talking about steps 5 & 6.

Comment: @Macmade no, for the same reason. They cant find makefile.gcc. I have tried to access this file from his catalogue or from direct path and still dont work

Comment: Well, step #3 changes the directory to `C:\wxWidgets-3.0.4\build\msw` so when the fourth command looks for `makefile.gcc`, it will expect to find the file `C:\wxWidgets-3.0.4\build\msw\makefile.gcc`.  Does that file exist?

Comment: @MadScientist Yup, this file exists in this directory.

Comment: So does `makefile.gcc` actually contain a `clean` target?

Comment: @Macmade Could you explain more or give example?

Comment: Maybe you should post the contents of the makefile...

Comment: @Macmade Its long so i have to copy this in .doc    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_fr7v4u7wcponmphInnlfCcjQ1LUewMW1qcI31Fk528

Comment: @donq104, can you post a log from Terminal after trying those commands? Also, can you try `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0`? All this online crap about building wxWidgets should be updated...

Comment: @Igor This is the same message error: https://pastebin.com/S4LaBXk6

Comment: @donq104, could you please edit the OP and place it there. It is just coup[le of lines from the Terminal... I am behind a very hard firewall and it is better to place it inline for other people references.

Comment: The "CreateProcess...failed" error usually happens when you have more than one MinGW installations on your system path.  To see if that's the case, you can type "echo %PATH%" into the shell and see if more than one mingw32\bin or mingw64\bin folder is listed in the output.

Comment: @NewPagodi So there is my PATH: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\texlive\2019\bin\win32;C:\MinGW\bin;            So is this possible that Git\mingw64 is in conflit with Mingw\bin?

Comment: I would try to remove the Git\mingw64\bin one from the path.  How to do that depends on your system, so I can give specific directions.  For one command prompt only you can type "set PATH=" and then type/paste in everything above except "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;" but that will only last for one shell only and reset the next time a new shell is opened.